# Why does static IP in Ubuntu 16 work only like this?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

We have a windows server with DHCP and 2 Linux machines with Ubuntu 16

if we set /etc/network/interfaces like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.18
netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then all works fine. So in short, first the machine sets static IP then it uses DHCP and it gets that ip 192.168.1.18

And if we delete those two last lines:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

There is no internet at all on the machine. Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: You didn't specify a `gateway`. The OS doesn't know where to route packets for the Internet. Using DHCP, the gateway's IP address would be supplied by the DHCP server.

Comment: This can be, I will try

Comment: You're also not setting any `dns-nameservers`

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, but there is one more thing now I figured it out that this is not ubuntu server, It's a Debian. does this matter at all?
P.S. I have network with your proposal but no internet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can anyone explain this please?" Yes, your interfaces file is seriously deficient. You have not specified a gateway nor the very important DNS nameservers.

I suggest that you amend the file to:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.18
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug eth0
```

Please be certain that the specified static IP address is outside the DHCP range in the router to avoid collisions.

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Confirm that you are connected:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :(, maybe because this is not ubuntu but Debian?

Comment: Probably not. Have you confirmed that the requested static IP address is outside the DHCP pool used in the router? Have you confirmed that the gateway address is actually x.1 and not x.254 or some other? You can check other devices on the same network; i.e. phones, iPads, etc.. Finally, in `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0`, the -v for verbose should produce some clues as to the success or failure of the connection. What does it say?